# Empty output while iterating through an xmltree iterator in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xmltree iterator that I am getting after parsing an xml file. This xml file has bunch of xml tags but I want to extract a specific set of tags that are in an order. My sample xmls file looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Version>16.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>9888</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>15360</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="m5479808">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="m5479828">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s64">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s65">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s72">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s73">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s74">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s76">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s78">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s79">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="###0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s80">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="###0.00"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s81">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s82">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="###0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s83">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="###0.00"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s84">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s85">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="##,##0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s86">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="####0.00"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s87">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="##,##0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s88">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="####0.00"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s89">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s90">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s91">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s92">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s98">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s99">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s100">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s101">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s102">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s103">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s104">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s105">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s106">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
     ss:Color="#000000"/>
   </Borders>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s108">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial, Helvetica" ss:Size="9" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s109">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Dataset Contents">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="6" ss:ExpandedRowCount="86" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:StyleID="s62" ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.4">
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="33.6"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="108"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="67.8" ss:Span="1"/>
   <Column ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="94.8"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="229.8"/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="31.95">
    <Cell ss:MergeAcross="5" ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Students Score Summary</Data></Cell>
   </Row>

  <!--...bunch of <Row><Cell><Data> tags which I don't want to extract..-->

  <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Variable Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Variable Label</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s79"><Data ss:Type="String">Minimum&#10;Value</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s79"><Data ss:Type="String">Maximum&#10;Value</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s80"><Data ss:Type="String">Mean&#10;Value</Data></Cell>

   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Marks</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Marks of Student</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">96</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s83"><Data ss:Type="Number">65.71</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Name of Students</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">n/a</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">n/a</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s83"><Data ss:Type="Number">n/a</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
    .
    .
    .
</Workbook>
```

Now what I want is when the tag name is `Marks` then check if next tag is `Marks of Student`. If it is then extract/print these two tags and next 3 tags(which would be Minimum,Maximum, and Mean values). My current updated code after suggestions is:

```
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.etree.ElementTree

tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('xmlFile1.xml').getroot()
parent_map = {c: p for p in tree.getiterator() for c in p}

def search_data(first_text, next_text):
    data_with_marks = [data_node
                       for data_node in tree.findall(".//Data")
                       if data_node.text == first_text]
    for marks_elem in data_with_marks:
        cell_elem = parent_map[marks_elem]
        row_elem = parent_map[cell_elem]
        cell_nodes = list(row_elem)
        curr_index = cell_nodes.index(cell_elem)
        next_index = curr_index + 1
        next_data_node = next(iter(cell_nodes[next_index]))
        if next_data_node.text == next_text:
            return [next(iter(cell_node))
                    for cell_node in cell_nodes[curr_index:curr_index + 6]]
    return []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for node in search_data("Marks", "Marks of Student"):
        print(node.text)
```

When I run the above code nothing gets print out. The executes with 0 return code and nothing appears to be printed. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Are you using `lxml`?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree`

Comment: First and foremost you have a namespace prefix `ss` that is no where declared in your posted example making it a not well-formed XML. Are there tags above `<Cell>`? You cannot just cut and paste from a larger XML document.

Comment: @Parfait Yes there are tags above <Cell>. i have mentioned that its a sample of the original full xml. Original XML file is very big so i have just pasted the part that I was working on with.

Comment: Namespaces are **very** important in parsing XML, hence why you receive no output. For a reproducible example involving XML files, always provide the root tag that usually defines namespaces.

Comment: @Parfait added root tag definition for ss and others in my post above

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement compares a Element with a string:

```
if next(xmlTree.iter()) == 'Marks of Student':
    ...
```

Try:

```
if next(xmlTree.iter()).text == 'Marks of Student':
    ...
```

But, the next element of a `<Data/>` element is a `<Cell/>` element, not the next `<Data/>`.

**EDIT**

Well, the solution is not easy to implement without full support of XPath and a good API. It's better to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

But, here is an implementation:

First, I completed you XML to make it parsable:

```
content = """\
<fragment xmlns:ss="foo">
<Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Variable Name</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Variable Label</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s79"><Data ss:Type="String">Minimum&#10;Value</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s79"><Data ss:Type="String">Maximum&#10;Value</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s80"><Data ss:Type="String">Mean&#10;Value</Data></Cell>

<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Marks</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Marks of Student</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">96</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s83"><Data ss:Type="Number">65.71</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15">
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"><Data ss:Type="String">Name of Students</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">n/a</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s82"><Data ss:Type="Number">n/a</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s83"><Data ss:Type="Number">n/a</Data></Cell>
</Row>
</fragment>
"""
```

I parse the string content like this:

```
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

istream = io.StringIO(content)
tree = ET.parse(istream)
```

Here is a trick to have a parent/children relationship:

```
parent_map = {c: p for p in tree.getiterator() for c in p}
```

The following function search for the first occurence of two consecutive Data which first text is *first_text* and next text is *next_text*:

```
def search_data(first_text, next_text):
    data_with_marks = [data_node
                       for data_node in tree.findall("//Data")
                       if data_node.text == first_text]
    for marks_elem in data_with_marks:
        cell_elem = parent_map[marks_elem]
        row_elem = parent_map[cell_elem]
        cell_nodes = list(row_elem)
        curr_index = cell_nodes.index(cell_elem)
        next_index = curr_index + 1
        next_data_node = next(iter(cell_nodes[next_index]))
        if next_data_node.text == next_text:
            return [next(iter(cell_node))
                    for cell_node in cell_nodes[curr_index:curr_index + 6]]
    return []
```

You can use this function like this:

```
for node in search_data("Marks", "Marks of Student"):
    print(node.text)
```

You get:

```
Marks
Marks of Student
0
96
65.71
```

Or:

```
for node in search_data("Name", "Name of Students"):
    print(node.text)
```

You get:

```
Name
Name of Students
n/a
n/a
n/a
```

See online demo on [repl.it](https://repl.it/HU02/latest)

Comment: I tried `if next(xmlTree.iter()).text == 'Age of Patient': print('Yes')` but still I get no output

Comment: Also if the problem is because of next element being `<Cell/>` and not `<Data/>` then how can I match the values for `<Data/>`?

Comment: I tried the update code but I am still getting nothing print out. I have updated my post to reflect current code

Comment: I have also provided my full xml content before the` <Row><Cell><Data>` tags starts to appear.

Comment: Sorry, TL;TR. I recommend you to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) and XPath to do what you want. Because of the complexity.

Comment: Can you show how can I get the output using `lxml` and `XPath`?